# Need to reference a variable before it is called in Python Flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm trying to reference the variable "found_user" which is an object of the class User, defined in an if statement whenever someone first logs in to the home page. I want the id of the user to be used to create a unique profile page but when I try to reference found_user._id it says

`NameError: name 'found_user' is not defined`

What is a solution to this? I tried declaring a global variable but that didn't do anything.

```
@app.route("/")
def home():
    url_for('static', filename='style.css')
    request_1 = request.url
    if request_1 != redirect_uri:
        code = request_1[28:-7]
        link_1 = f"https://spookvooper.com/oauth2/RequestToken?grant_type=authorization_code&code={code}&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}&client_id={client_id}&client_secret={client_secret}"
        request_1 = requests.get(link_1).text
        request_data = json.loads(request_1)

        session["access_token"] = request_data["access_token"]
        session["expires_in"] = request_data["expires_in"]
        session["svid"] = request_data["svid"]

        svid = session["svid"]
        user_link = f"https://api.spookvooper.com/User/GetUser?svid={svid}"
        user_request = requests.get(user_link).text
        user_load = json.loads(user_request)
        session["username"] = user_load["userName"]

        global found_user
        found_user = Users.query.filter_by(user_svid = session["svid"]).first()
             
        if found_user:
            session["balance"] = found_user.balance

        else:
            usr = Users(session["svid"], session["username"], 0)
            session["balance"] = usr.balance
            db.session.add(usr)
            db.session.commit()
        return render_template("logged_in.html", auction1 = link)
    else:
        if "svid" not in session:
            return render_template("index.html", auction1 = link)
        else:
            return render_template("logged_in.html", auction1 = link)

@app.route("/login/")
def login():
    return redirect(login_oauth)

@app.route(f"/profile/{found_user._id}")
def profile():
    if "svid" in session:
        svid = session["svid"]
        user_link = f"https://api.spookvooper.com/User/GetUser?svid={svid}"
        user_request = requests.get(user_link).text
        user_load = json.loads(user_request)
        return render_template("profile.html", username = user_load["userName"], bal = session["balance"])
    else:
        return redirect(login_oauth)
```

Comment: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#variable-rules

Comment: Do you have `found_user = None` above `def home():`?

Comment: is it possible that your database is empty ad first and you need to fill it in first ?

Comment: @GAEfan putting found_user = None gives ```AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_id'```

Comment: @SebNik My database isn't empty but I need to create the found_user variable which will point towards the user's datapoint in the database, which I can only do once the person has logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Several issues, but let's start with this one:

```
@app.route(f"/profile/{found_user._id}")
def profile():
```

You are not using `found_user._id` so not sure what you are tryng to do here.  It should either be:

```
@app.route(f"/profile")
def profile():
```

or:

```
@app.route(f"/profile/{found_user_id}")
def profile(found_user_id = found_user._id): # assuming you really have found_user as a global, which sounds like a bad approach.
```

Which brings us to next issue... Where are you defining `found_user`?  Are you trying to use it as a global, but only after a visit to `/`?

I do not see anywhere in your code where `found_user` needs to be a global.  It is only being used in `home()`.

Comment: GAEfan already mentioned a few points. 
I would add that if you want to save information between requests you should use session.